# Univalent Blaschke Products on $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis, blaschke-products

Let $B$ be a finite Blaschke product of degree $n$. Suppose there exist an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{D}$ such that $B$ is univalent on $U.$ Is it true that $n=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As a holomorphic function, $B$ is univalent in some neighborhood of any point $z_0$ with $B'(z_0) \ne 0$, and for a non-constant function the zeros of the derivative are isolated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can we prove this or Can you give me a reference for this?

Comment: That should be in any book about complex analysis. I am on the phone currently and therefore restricted in the search capabilities,  but here is a possible reference: http://www.math.unipd.it/~pietro/doc/Complex_Analysis/De%20Marco%20-%20Selected%20topics%20of%20Complex%20Analysis2012.pdf

Comment: Thank you for you link. I spend few hours on it and I think now I understand it :) If I change the problem as : There exist an open set $V$ of $\mathbb{D}$ such that  $B^{-1}(z)$ is singleton for each $z\in V.$" Is above result still valid?

Comment: @Nilan: A finite Blaschke product of degree $n$ takes each value in the unit disk exactly $n$ times (counted with multiplicity). Therefore, your new condition implies that $n=1$.